# JS: setInterval running as if there were multiple intervals set

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, I've been trying to figure out JS, and what better way to do so than to make a small project. It's a small trivia game, and it has a question timer I've made using setInterval. Unfortunately, after answering multiple questions, the interval's behaviour gets very weird - it runs the command twice every time. I guess it's my faulty implementation of buttonclicks?
By the way, if my code is awful I am sorry, I've been desperate to fix the issue and messed with it a lot.

```
function startGame(){
    if (clicked === true){
        return;
    }
    else{
        $("#textPresented").html("Which anthem is this?");
        $("#button").css("display", "none");
        currentCountry = getRndInteger(0,8);
        console.log(currentCountry);
        var generatedURL = anthemnflags[currentCountry];
        console.log(generatedURL);
        audios.setAttribute("src", generatedURL);
        audios.play();
        $("#button").html("I know!");
        $("#button").css("display", "block");
        $("#button").click(function () { 
            continueManager();
    
        });
        
        y=10;
        console.log("cleared y" + y);
        x = setInterval(function(){
            y = y - 1;
           console.log("Counting down..." + y)
        }, 1000);
        console.log("INTERVAL SET");
    }

}
```

Here is the console output:

```
cleared y10 flaggame.js:59:17
INTERVAL SET flaggame.js:64:17
AbortError: The fetching process for the media resource was aborted by the user agent at the user's request. flaggame.js:49
Counting down...9 flaggame.js:62:20 ---- THESE TWO ARE BEING PRINTED AT THE SAME TIME
Counting down...8 flaggame.js:62:20 ---- THESE TWO ARE BEING PRINTED AT THE SAME TIME
Counting down...7 flaggame.js:62:20 
Counting down...6 flaggame.js:62:20
Counting down...5 flaggame.js:62:20
Counting down...4 flaggame.js:62:20
Counting down...3 flaggame.js:62:20
Counting down...2 flaggame.js:62:20
Counting down...1 flaggame.js:62:20
Counting down...0
```

THE REST OF MY CODE:

```
function middleGame(){
    $("#button").css("display", "none");
    var n = document.querySelectorAll(".flagc").length;
    correctIMG = getRndInteger(0,n-1);
    showFlags();
    var taken = new Array();
    for (var i = 0; i < n; ++i){
        if (i === correctIMG){
            images[i].attr("src", "res/" + flagsfiles[currentCountry]);
            taken[currentCountry] = true;
        }
        else{
            var randomFlag = getRndInteger(0, flagsfiles.length);
            if (randomFlag !== currentCountry && taken[randomFlag] !== true){
                images[i].attr("src", "res/" + flagsfiles[randomFlag]);
                taken[randomFlag] = true;   
            }
        }
    }
        $(".flagc").click(function(){
            clickregister(this);   
        });
}
function continueManager(){
    if (!clicked){
        audios.pause()
        clearInterval(x);
        x = 0;
        clicked = true;
        middleGame();
        return;
    }
}
function clickregister(buttonClicked){
        if ($(buttonClicked).attr("id") != correctIMG){
            points = points - 1;
            flagARR[$(buttonClicked).attr("id")].css("display", "none");
            console.log("INCORRECT");
        }
        else{
            if (y >= 0) {
                var addedPoints = 1 + y;
                points = points + addedPoints;
                
                $("#points").html(points);
            }
            else{
                points = points + 1;
            }
            hideFlags();
            clicked = false;
            startGame();
        }
}
$(function(){

hideFlags();
$("#textPresented").html("When you're ready, click the button below!");
$("#button").html("I am ready!");
$("#button").click(function () { 
    if (!gameStarted){
        gameStarted = true;
        alert("STARTING GAME");
        startGame();
    }

    
});
});
```

Basically this is how it works:
When the "I am ready" button is clicked, startGame() is called. It plays a random tune and counts down, until the player hits the "I know" button. That button SHOULD stop the interval and start the middleGame() function, which shows 4 images, generates a random correct image and awaits input, checks if it's true, then launches startGame() again.
The first and second cycles are perfect - after the third one things get messy.

I also noticed that the "INCORRECT" log gets printed twice, why?

EDIT: here is the minimized code that has the same issue:

```
var x;
var gameStarted = false;
var y;
var clicked;
$(function(){
$("#button").click(function () { 
    if (!gameStarted){
        gameStarted = true;
        startGame();
    } 
});
});
function startGame(){
    console.log("startgame()");
    if (clicked === true){
        return;
    }
    else{
    console.log("!true");
        $("#button").css("display", "block");
        $("#button").click(function () { 
            continueManager();
        });
        y=10;
        x = setInterval(function(){
            y = y - 1;
            console.log(y);
        }, 1000);
    }

}
function continueManager(){
    if (!clicked){
        clearInterval(x);
        x = 0;
        clicked = true;
        middleGame();
        return;
    }
}
function middleGame(){
    $("#button").css("display", "none");
    var taken = new Array();
    $(".flagc").click(function(){
        clickregister(this);   
    });
}
function clickregister(buttonClicked){
        console.log("clickgregister"); 
        //Irrelevant code that checks the answers
        clicked = false;
        startGame();
}
```

EDIT2: It appears that my clickregister() function gets called twice, and that function then calls startGame() twice.

EDIT3: I have found the culprit! It's these lines of code:

```
    $(".flagc").click(function(){
        console.log("button" + $(this).attr("id") + "is clicked");
        clickregister(this);   
    });
```

They get called twice, for the same button

Comment: Can you reduce this to a [minimal, complete, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) please, that runs in a snippet here?

Comment: Just a wild guess, maybe you have nested HTML elements both with the class `flagc`, so clicking the inner one triggers a click event on both?

Comment: Maybe even accidentally - maybe you have two flags that are supposed to be adjacent but by accident the tags are not closed correctly and the first one ends up _containing_ the second one

Comment: I am pretty sure that everything is fine with my tags, as the first and second questions work as intended

Comment: after some digging, it appears that my Clickregister function gets called twice, and it calls startgame twice as well.I have also double checked my HTML tags, it shouldn't click twice

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it!
It turns out all I had to do was to add

```
$(".flagc").unbind('click');
```

Before the .click() function!

Comment: Yep, I see that now too, otherwise every time the game starts, _another_ listener is added

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear the interval first then call it again. You can do that by creating a variable outside of the event listener scope and in the event listener check if the variable contains anything if yes then clear the interval of x. After clearing the interval you can reset it.

Something like this:

```
<button class="first" type="submit">Button</button>

const btn = document.querySelector('.first');
let x;

btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    x && clearInterval(x)
    x = setInterval(() => console.log("yoo"), 500)
})
```

This is because if you don't clear the interval of x it will create a new one on every button press.